# Discord.py как сделать отправку сообщений в первый по счету канал на сервере?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Допустим есть код:

```js
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    print("Join to " + guild.name)
    guild_to_audiocontroller[guild] = AudioController(bot, guild)
    await guild_to_audiocontroller[guild].register_voice_channel(guild.voice_channels[0])
    channel = bot.get_channel[0]
    await channel.send(join_message)
```

Оно конечно же не работает. Как сделать отправку сообщений в первый по счету канал(который находится выше всех в списке), если я не знаю id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    print("Join to " + guild.name)
    guild_to_audiocontroller[guild] = AudioController(bot, guild)
    await guild_to_audiocontroller[guild].register_voice_channel(guild.voice_channels[0])
    channel = guild.text_channels[0]
    await channel.send(join_message)
```